# Oracle PL/SQL: How do I filter out whitespaces in SELECT?

Tags: select, plsql, whitespace

I have a table `mytable` that has a column `ngram` which is a `VARCHAR2`. I want to SELECT only those rows where `ngram` does not contain any whitespaces (tabs, spaces, EOLs etc). What should I replace `<COND>` below with?

```
SELECT ngram FROM mytable WHERE <COND>;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regexp_instr (or regexp_like, or other regexp functions), see [here](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/regular-expressions-support-in-oracle.php#example6) for example

```
  where  regexp_instr(ngram, '[ '|| CHR(10) || CHR(13) || CHR(9) ||']') = 0
```

the white space is managed here `'[ '`

- chr(10)  = line feed
- chr(13) = carriage return
- chr(9) = tab

Answer (score 1):

you can use **CHR** and **INSTR** function  ASCII code of the characters you want to filter for example your where clause can be like this for an special character:

```
 INSTR(ngram,CHR(the ASCI CODE of special  char))=0
```

or the condition  can be like this:

```
where 
and ngram not like '%'||CHR(0)||'%' -- for null
.
.
.
and ngram not like '%'||CHR(31)||'%' -- for unit separator
and ngram not like '%'||CHR(127)||'%'-- for delete
```

here you can get all codes http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/non-breaking-space-no-break-space-ascii-code-255.html

Comment: ... multiple times for each special character passing the condition of being *whitespace*.

Answer (score 1):

This should match ngram where it contains no whitespace characters by using the \s shorthand for all whitespace characters.  I only tested by inserting a TAB into a string in a VARCHAR2 column and it was then excluded:

```
where regexp_instr(ngram, '\s') = 0;
```